# Convolution with Schwartz class function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $f, g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$ (Schwartz class function), $\delta_0$ ([dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)).

Consider  distribution as follows:
 $$H(x, y)= f(x)g(x)\delta_0(y)-f(y)g(y)\delta_0(x), \ (x, y\in \mathbb R)$$

Let $h(x,y)= e^{-(x^2+y^2)}.$

My Question is:

> Can we expect  that $H\ast h \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^2)$?

where $\ast$ denotes the convolution.

Comment: I just answered on math.stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005057/convolution-with-gaussian which is preferable to MO for non research questions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. Indeed, for any Schwartz function $\phi$ we have $(h*G)(\phi)=G(h^-*\phi)=G(h*\phi)$, where $h^-(x,y):=h(-x,-y)=h(x,y)=e^{-x^2-y^2}$. So,
\begin{multline}
 (h*G)(\phi)=G(h*\phi)=\int dx\,f(x)g(x)\iint du\,dv\,\phi(u,v)e^{-(x-u)^2-v^2} \\ 
 -\int dy\,f(y)g(y)\iint du\,dv\,\phi(u,v)e^{-u^2-(y-v)^2}  \\ 
 =\int dx\,f(x)g(x)\iint du\,dv\,\phi(u,v)[e^{-(x-u)^2-v^2}-e^{-u^2-(x-v)^2}] \\ 
 =\iint du\,dv\,\phi(u,v)p(u,v),
\end{multline}
where 
\begin{equation}
 p(u,v):=\int dx\,f(x)g(x)[e^{-(x-u)^2-v^2}-e^{-u^2-(x-v)^2}]. 
\end{equation}
We have 
\begin{multline}
 \iint du\,dv\,|p(u,v)|\le2\int dx\,|f(x)g(x)|\iint du\,dv\,e^{-(x-u)^2-v^2} \\ 
 =2\int dx\,|f(x)g(x)|\,c^2<\infty, 
\end{multline}
where $c:=\int dv\,e^{-v^2}<\infty$. 
So, 
\begin{equation}
 (h*G)(\phi)=\iint p\phi, 
\end{equation}
and $p\in L^1$.